# filling a zero matrix corresponding to row and column numbers

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a matrix (for example A) it has n*3 dimension the first column is row numbers and the second column is column number and third column are height value.

I have a zero matrix with i*j dimension. now I want put height values(third column) in zero matrix (B) corresponding to row (first column) and column (second column) of that height.

For example:

```
A=[5,4,108;1,3,105;3,3,98]
B=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Now I want put 108 in row=5 and column=4 in zero matrix and put 105 in row=1 and column=3 in zero matrix and etc.

`B=[0 0 105 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 98 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 108 0 0 0]`

I want to do this work without  " for " loops .

Comment: This is very basic. Read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

Comment: All your previous questions have pretty good answers. You've not accepted any answer in any of your previous questions. Consider upvoting / marking the most helpful answers as accepted to return some favor to the people who are volunteering to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sardar pointed out [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) is in the documentation.  The specific command you will need is `sub2ind` [documented here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).  This converts row, column subscript pairs into linear indices.

Step 1 get linear index of the row/column pairs defined in A.

```
idx = sub2ind(size(B), A(:,1), A(:,2));
```

Step 2 assign values at those indices in B to the values of the 3rd column in A.

```
B(idx) = A(:,3)

B =

     0     0   105     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0    98     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0   108     0     0     0
```

Comment: Hello, I really appreciate of your guides .thank you very much .